# How to use Windows system variables in Flutter for Destop app?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to use Windows system environment variables in Flutter for Destop app (like %APPDATA%, %LOCALAPPDATA% and others)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`Platform.environment`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.1/dart-io/Platform/environment.html) property to get the `APPDATA` and `LOCALAPPDATA` environment variables. `Platform.environment` is a `Map<String, String?>` where the key is the name of the environment variable and the value the current environment variable value.

Code example:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final appData = Platform.environment['APPDATA'];
  final localAppData = Platform.environment['LOCALAPPDATA'];
  print('APPDATA = $appData');
  print('LOCALAPPDATA = $localAppData');
}
```

**Output**

```
APPDATA = C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local
```